# Why is form object not available during controller initialization in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Consider the following html

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
    <form name="myForm"></form>
</div>
```

and controller file

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('myApp')
        .controller('myController', myController);

    myController.$inject = ['$scope', '$interval'];

    function myController($scope, $interval) {
        var myFormDetector = $interval(function() {
            if ($scope.myForm) {
                console.log('form exist');
                $interval.cancel(myFormDetector);
            } else {
                console.log('form not exist');
            } 

        }, 200)
    }
})();
```

I observe that `form not exist` at least prints once?

This is very curious as I thought that the order of rendering is

```
compile
controller
link
```

so by the time `controller` is intialized, `compile` should render the html and inject the `$scope`?

Am I getting anything wrong?

Comment: The controller of the parent element is created before the child element is. Generally speaking, the child elements should 'talk' to the parent element, not the other way around. Other ways indicate coupling.

Answer (score 1):

The controller of the parent element will be created and linked before the child element. If you want the parent element to know about the child form, you probably want to do something like this:

```
<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller='myController'>
  <form name='myForm' ng-init='myController.onInit()'>
  </form>
</div>
```

```
function MyController($scope) {
  this.$scope = $scope
}

MyController.prototype.onInit = function onInit() {
  this.$scope.myForm....
}
```

This isn't very sustainable though, and it's considered bad practice to use `ngController` like this. This pattern is common though, so common in fact that Angular has bindings for components for it (Angular 1.5+)

```
<div ng-app='myApp'>
  <x-parent-component>
    <form name='ngForm'>
    </form>
  </x-parent-component>
</div>
```

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .component('xParentComponent', {
    controller: XParentComponentCtrl,
    transclude: true,
    template: '<div ng-transclude></ng-transclude>'
  })

function XParentComponentCtrl($scope) {
  this.$scope = $scope
}
XParentComponentCtrl.prototype.$postLink = function $postLink() {
  this.$scope.myForm...
}
```

Are you *sure* you want to do this though? It probably indicates high coupling if your *parent* element talks to *child* elements like this. You should probably consider having the communication be the other way around; the *child* components tell the *parent* component about changes.